# Does anyone have a coding standard documentation for Rust programming on Solana?

Tags: solana-program, rust, anchor-lang

I have written smart contract in Rust using Anchor framework on Solana blockchain. I need to make sure that I'm following all the right coding standards. So if anyone happens to have a coding standard guideline documentation then please share the link with me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use solanacookbook for a reference book.
https://solanacookbook.com/

For rust part, you can reference your functions on this site.
https://docs.rs

And for web3 part, you can reference this.
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/